# java applet RuntimeException Java.lang.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, applet, runtime-error, japplet, invocationtargetexception

I have written a very basic applet, as I have only begun learning. This particular applet should only show some text, however whenever I run this locally (I have configured java to medium security) or from the server, I get the following error with no details:

```
RuntimeException Java.lang.InvocationTargetException
```

I have tried using Chrome, Firefox, IE but I get the same error message for all of them.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <applet code="app.class" width="400" height="400"></applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my java code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class app extends JApplet {
    public void paint (Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("GIO", 15, 25);
    }
}
```

This is where my applet is:
http://testingsomestuff.netne.net/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Jenny  In this case, your advice is a little like telling the dinosaurs *"Well you should have just **caught** the meteor"*..

Comment: Post the entire stack trace. You've omitted the most important part. The very next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An applet **has to** be declared `public`.  So:

```
class app extends JApplet {
```

Should be:

```
public class app extends JApplet {
```

### Tips

1) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

2) Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.

3) The `code` attribute should be the FQN, not the file name, so:

```html
    <applet code="app.class" width="400" height="400"></applet>
```

Should be:

```html
    <applet code="app" width="400" height="400"></applet>
```